# Display form after submit in PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html, forms

Using the code below, I'm having trouble with showing form responses on submit. I've tried a mix of _GET and _POST, but I don't understand what to use and when because I'm relatively new to PHP. How could the code show form responses on submit?

```php
<?php {

$fDogErr = $lDogErr = "";

// only show the information if the button named "subButton" has been pressed
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // set the variable with the submitted value
     if (empty($fDog = $_POST['favourite dog'])) {
         $fDogErr = "Need favourite dog";
     } else {
         $fDog = $_POST['favourite dog'];
     }   
         
     if (empty ($lDog = $_POST['least favourite dog'])) {
         $lDogErr = "Need least favourite dog";
     } else {
         $lDog = $_POST['least favourite dog'];
     }   
         
         if (empty($password = $_POST['pawsword'])) {
         $password = "";
     } else {
         $password = $_POST['password'];
     }   
        
     if (empty($dogcac = $_POST['dogcac'])) {
         $dogcac = "";
     } else {
         $dogcac = $_POST['dogcac'];
     }
    
         
    $secretdoggo = $_POST['secretdoggo'];

}

    // display the user inputs to the screen
    
    echo "<p>Your favourite dog is <b>" . $fDog . "</b>.</p>";
    echo "<p>Your least favourite dog is <b>"  . $lDog . "</b>.</p>";
    echo "<p>Your pawsword is <b>" . $password . "</b>.</p>";
    echo "<p> Did you know? <b>" . $secretdoggo . "</b>.</p>";
    

}

?>
```

Comment: where is the html / form for this?

Comment: First off `if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` with your conditional `empty()`'s will never work since they never clicked the submit to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an HTML form with all the input tags defined first. The form tag has an **action** attribute that states where the data will be sent (the PHP you linked), a **method** (POST, GET etc..) and a button with **type** submit that triggers the sending of the form data. The PHP file can then show your form responses when the submit button is clicked.

See the example below:

> Form HTML Example:

```
<form method="post" action="response.php">
    <label>Password:</label> <input type="text" id="favourite_dog" name="favourite_dog" /> 
    <label>Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
     more input tags . . .
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> PHP Example Showing Responses:

response.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)){
   $favourite_dog = $_POST['favourite_dog'];
   $password= $_POST['password'];

   echo "<p>Your favourite dog is <b>" . $favourite_dog . "</b>.</p>";       
}
```

Hope this helps.